# How to list the compound words from a dictionary

Tags: algorithms

For Example my input is this dictionary
s=["noon", "n", "o", "noo", "Good", "Goodnoon", "marry", "me", "marryme", "air", "r", "airbag"]. The output should be a list of compound words. like Good noon, airbag.

Comment: Just produce another list with all words concatenated with all others, and then filter the dictionary based on matches in the concatenated list.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Don't confuse a how-to-write-code question with an algorithm question. ["we eliminated the line item for "algorithms and data structures". But this doesn't mean that these questions are off-topic, because they aren't." Tomas Owens](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8184/131624). See also [is "what algorithm could solve my problem" off topic](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8213/is-what-algorithm-could-solve-my-problem-off-topic/8214#8214)? So far this question hasn't attracted the kinds of answers we wish to avoid.

Comment: @CandiedOrange: Admittedly, that's wider than I thought it was. Re-reading the question though, it's unclear which one the OP wants.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield useful to the op is not the criteria. Its whether it's useful to others.

Comment: @CandiedOrange: I concur. So when in doubt, it's best to assume the OP is asking the question they ought to have asked?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield doing that helps not only the site but helps the op get something useful out of us. Even if it's not exactly what they expected.

Comment: well, it seems that "noon" would be a compound word as well, as it is made of "noo" and "n".

Comment: This seems decidedly off-topic to me. Unless we've come full circle and we accept programming questions again (instead of redirecting them to StackOverflow), in which case, welcome back P.SE! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach is to generate the compounds from dictionary:

Check for inclusion of the concatenation of the Cartesian product of the dictionary with itself. This finds that ('Good', 'noon') occurs as 'Goodnoon' appears in the dictionary.

This can be made faster with a prefix [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (string prefix index) over the dictionary and by avoiding the direct method of taking the Cartesian product and not actually concatenating. I will not describe the implementation.  In case it is allowed to start with an unknown prefix and finish with a known word, a suffix trie should also be used.

One can also approach this as breaking up compound words:

It means for 'Goodnoon' given a dictionary of words find the words that make up the compound. In this case: [('Good', 'noon')]. The output of this can be reduced to the prior problem by reducing the set of partitions to non-emptiness.

To solve this one finds for all words that are a prefix of this word and then all words that are prefixes of the compound with the prior word removed, this is repeated until there are no matching words or the compound is reduced to the empty string. At each step, this is a prefix intersection problem between a prefix index and a suffix index.

Comment: Excellent answer ! However, if you would replace "air" with "bag" in the list, "airbag" would still be a compound word, isn't it ? So I propose to consider both prefix and suffix trie.  It must be said that all other methods would fail for large dictionaries of several thousands of words.

Comment: I think the OP was mistaken to include "airbag" in the output without both "air" and "bag" in the input.  If only a prefix or suffix is required, but not both, that would make words like "there" be considered compound if "the" was in the list.

Comment: It seems my list  [('Good', 'noon')] also contains ('Good','noo','n') and ('Good','n','o,'o','n').

Answer (score 0):

A compound word starts with another word. So the first step would be to sort the words by length, and try shorter words as prefixes of longer words.

Those that have another word as a prefix make it to the next round, where you try to see if they continue past the point of the prefix with another shorter word. It's convenient to keep the words as a list of *parts:* (prefix, remaining part), so split them once you detect the prefix, and only check the remaining part.

With some care, this works for compound words consisting of more than 2 parts. Expect funny results with compound words that are parts of linger compound words: ["foo", "bar", "baz", "foobar", "foobarbaz"].

Comment: not sure that it always start with a word of the list.  If you would replace "air" with "bag" in the list, "airbag" would still be a compound word, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, but you _still_ would need to have `air` on the list, too? Else `asdfghjklbag` would be considered a compound word. The idea of a compound word, in my book, is that it consists of other words strung together, _and of nothing else._

Comment: I'm not sure, because in the example "airbag" is compound and only "air" is in the list.